# Using data from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, information-schema

I'm trying to get table names out of a database depending on user input (different tables required for different queries).  I have the following code:

```
function getTables(){

    $dbConn = new dbConn();
    $conn = $dbConn->connect();

    $data = $conn->query('SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "dbName" AND table_name LIKE "' . $this->table . '%";');

    $tables = $data->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($tables as $item) {
        echo $item;
        }

    return $tables;

}
```

The output from the above is ArrayArrayArrayArray which leads me to believe I'm dealing with an array of arrays.  When I print_r($tables) I get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ([table_name] => my_table0) [1] => Array ([table_name] => my_table1) etc. etc.
```

How can I get the actual table names out of this to use in a query?

Comment: Yes, `fetchAll()` returns a 2D array of row arrays.  So in your loop, `echo $item['table_name']` since that's the key holding the table's name.

Comment: I'll add this advice: _use EXTREME caution_ when allowing user input to translate into query table names. You cannot bind table names as parameters and will have to take great care that you aren't permitting your users to execute queries against tables which should not be allowed.

Comment: Since you're using PDO, you should use prepared queries to insert user data. You can't do that for table names in ordinary queries, but you can with `information_schema`, since the table names are data there.

Comment: Marvellous, thanks Michael.  Now to assign those to variables ;)  And yes, I know I should be using prepared queries, this is just early stages to get to grips with PDO.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Okay Michael, now I understand.  I'm currently running the user input against a whitelist of tables and then using them in conjunction with prepared statements.  But, if you can't bind table names as parameters how can I write dynamic queries for multiple tables?

Comment: @OliverBurdekin You can still write dynamic queries, but you will have to use $variables rather than bound params for the table name (the WHERE and INSERT/UPDATE vars are still bound params).  That just means you have to thoroughly validate the contents of the table variable to be acceptable - don't just escape it against injection, you have to use the whitelist to be sure it contains exactly one of your allowed table names.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks so much for your help on this Michael. The user input is predefined dropdowns only (no typing).  the values from those are then checked against a hard coded array of tables (whitelist) and the $table variables then set using those.  $table variables are then used in a prepared query.  I hope that's pretty safe.

Comment: @OliverBurdekin Yes, I'd say that sounds safe.